# How to drop duplicates from a cartesian product in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cross-join

I have created a cross join of a set of words to compare their similarities between them in Spark. However I am trying to get rid off those entries that are repeated since the score for (word1, word2) = (word2, word1). I have the following table that looks something like this;

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|  col1 | col2  | score |
+-------+-------+-------+
| word1 | word1 |   1   |
| word1 | word2 | 0.345 |
| word1 | word3 | 0.432 |
| word2 | word1 | 0.345 |
| word2 | word2 |   1   |
| word2 | word3 | 0.543 |
| word3 | word1 | 0.432 |
| word3 | word2 | 0.543 |
| word3 | word3 |   1   |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Ideally I would like to obtain a result like this where no comparisons are repeated:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|  col1 | col2  | score |
+-------+-------+-------+
| word1 | word1 |   1   |
| word1 | word2 | 0.345 |
| word1 | word3 | 0.432 |
| word2 | word2 |   1   |
| word2 | word3 | 0.543 |
| word3 | word3 |   1   |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine `col1` and `col2` as a list, and alphabetically sort them using `sort_array`. Once sorted, doing a `.distinct()` on them will remove duplicates. Now you can unpack the list as `col1` and `col2`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import sort_array

df.withColumn("sorted_list", sort_array(F.array([F.col("col1"), F.col("col2")])))\
    .select("sorted_list", "score").distinct()\
    .select(F.col("sorted_list")[0].alias("col1"), \
    F.col("sorted_list")[1].alias("col2"), "score").show()
```

Output:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| col1| col2|score|
+-----+-----+-----+
|word1|word1|  1.0|
|word1|word2|0.345|
|word1|word3|0.432|
|word2|word2|  1.0|
|word2|word3|0.543|
|word3|word3|  1.0|
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Excellent, Thank you so much, I´ve been fighting this problem for over a week